# STEAM API | Проверка аккаунта на наличие игры

Tags: php, api, steam-web-api, steam

Как используя steam api проверить аккаунт на наличие csgo?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю это то, что надо https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29

Здесь можно найти еще несколько интересных методов API Steam https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamEconomy_GetAssetClassInfo_v1

Comment: Привет. Вижу вопрос по STEAM API. Вопрос, есть ли у Вас возможность скинуть код авторизации на сайт Steam`а ? Или же просто объяснить как мне самому можно разобраться с документацией ? Нашёл по этой ссылке : https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/steam.webauth.html

Comment: @VitalikShchudlo Это было давно. Уже не помню почти ничего. Я делал бота на node.js Можно посмотреть готовый набор модулей в сборке одного умельца( https://github.com/dragonbanshee/node-steam-parentbot ). Посмотрите код там. Для авторизации бота требуется номер, который генерирует мобильное приложение. Ключ для генерации этого номера можно получить из телефона с помощью программы SDA ( https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator ) . А номер из этого ключа можно сгенерировать с помощью модуля steam TOTP https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-totp, она есть в сборке указанной выше